# PHP imagefilter question

Tags: php, gd, imagefilter

Why does IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST in example 1 produce a brighter image then in example 2 can someone explain the IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST parameter in more detail me as why this happens?

Example 1

```
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, 255);
```

Example 2

```
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, 100);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP imagefilter parameter question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390053/php-imagefilter-parameter-question)

Answer (score 3):

According to [PHP: imagefilter - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php), it looks like 255 is outside of the range of values for `IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST`.

> The documentation misses the exact meaning and valid ranges of the arguments for `ImageFilter()`. According to the 5.2.0 sources the arguments are:
>   ...
>   `IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST`
>   -100 = max contrast, 0 = no change, +100 = min contrast (note the direction!)

Comment: then what is the official values and where is the official docs on this?

Comment: so are those the official values and what are 5.2.0 sources can someone point me to those?

Comment: @Matt Ball where are 5.2.0 sources located that talk about the values?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? You can download the complete source code to PHP 5.3.6 and 5.2.17 [here](http://www.php.net/downloads.php). I haven't looked through it myself; that was just a quote from the PHP Manual page I linked in my answer.

Comment: @Matt Ball I'm running the latest version but where are the docs that state the values you talk about where is documentation to back up these values?

Comment: ...you're kidding, right? As I said in my previous comment, the quote I included in my answer is a direct copy-and-paste from [a comment on the imagefilter manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php#72329).

Comment: its a comment not the 5.2.0 sources stated in the comment which is what I want.

Comment: I already commented, you can download the sources for PHP 5.3.6 and 5.2.17 at http://www.php.net/downloads.php. There's no point in looking through the source code of a version of PHP that you're not using.

Comment: Are you looking for the **source code,** or the **documentation?** I have already linked to **both of them.**

Comment: you just point to comments on the values and nothing more to support the values.

Answer (score 1):

As PanuWorld outlines in a comment in the docs - [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php#72329)

"...IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST
-100 = max contrast, 0 = no change, +100 = min contrast (note the direction!)
"...

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to hear from us as the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) says it is the constrast level and you are using different values in both calls.

That's why the output is different.

Comment: but it goes from light to dark and back to light?

Answer (score 0):

IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST: Changes the contrast of the image. Use arg1 to set the level of contrast.

IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST: Contrast level.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision)